# Private Pods with SVN repository

Tags: svn, cocoapods

We are working on a project which we want to include both open-source libraries and private libraries using CocoaPod tool. Private libraries are hosted in our company servers(using SVN repo) which we don't to make those as a public. We would like to use CocoaPods for all of them. While using open-source libs, it is pretty easy, but when we specify private dependency and install the Pod file, we are getting the below error in the terminal

[!] Unable to add a source with url SOURCE_URL named `xxxxx-svn-repos-pods`. You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

My Pod file looks like as

platform :ios, '7.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'TestPodProj' do

source 'https://xxxxxx.com/svn/repos/pods'

pod 'TestPods', '~> 0.0.1'

end

If we use $ pod repo add NAME SOURCE_URL command, we get

[!] /usr/bin/git clone SOURCE_URL SampleSpec

Cloning into 'SampleSpec'...

fatal: repository 'SOURCE_URL' not found

We thought this error could be because of git and the command "pod repo add" works only for git.

For SVN, I've found this link https://github.com/clarkda/cocoapods-repo-svn. So I have tried entering the below command to install cocoapod for Private Repo

$ pod repo-svn add SPEC_NAME   SOURCE_URL

It says checking out, but not downloaded.

Checking out spec-repo 'SPEC_NAME' from SOURCE_URL

Note: I have validated podspec file sitting in SVN repository.

How to install CocoaPods in Private SVN repo?